# How to set Cron Job in magento using custom Module?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.5, magento-1.6, magento

I want to use cron job or scheduling for my custom module in Magento.
I research about it but not able to found suitable answer which help me.

I created one form which allow user to select Day, hour, min, sec etc.. And I store all this values in database. What I want to do is that its takes value from database and Run some schedule (define php script) according to that time.
I don't have any Idea how can I do that. So, Please Help me to resolved this issue.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

The way the Magento Cron system is designed, is not really to allow user specified scheduling, but rather developer specified scheduling (i.e. the frequency of a task is set in a modules XML configuration, that can't be changed via the GUI). This being said, you can work around this somewhat by setting your Cron to run at the most frequent interval in the XML and wrap the code in the actual cron function, with code to compare the current time with the database configuration.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a cronjob that run every 'x interval' to check your database to see if anything is schedule. If something is schedule then execute else do nothing

See [How to Set Up a Cron Job](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using `config_path`

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>                
        <company_export_send_order>
            <schedule>
                <config_path>export/order/cron_settings</config_path>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>company_export/observer::exportOrderData</model>
            </run>
        </company_export_send_order>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Read more @ [magento cron in backend configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446934/magento-cron-in-backend-configuration)